# What's the best way to set up a per-test or per-class timeout when using <junit> in perBatch forkmode?

Tags: java, ant, junit, timeout, junit4

I want to fail the build if anyone writes a test that takes longer than 1 second to run, but if I run  in perTest mode it takes much, much longer.

I could probably write a custom task that parses the junit reports and fails the build based on that, but I was wondering if anyone knows or can think of a better option.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Reviving an old question since the answer doesn't provide an example.

You can specify timeout

1. Per test method:

   ```
    @Test(timeout = 100) // Exception: test timed out after 100 milliseconds
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
   ```
2. For all methods in a test class using [`Timeout`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/Timeout.html) `@Rule`:

   ```
    @Rule
    public Timeout timeout = new Timeout(100);

    @Test // Exception: test timed out after 100 milliseconds
    public void methodTimeout() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodInTime() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
   ```
3. Globally for the total time to run all test methods in the class using a static `Timeout` `@ClassRule`:

   ```
    @ClassRule
    public static Timeout classTimeout = new Timeout(200);

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(150);
    }

    @Test // InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
   ```
4. And even apply timeout (either `@Rule` or `@ClassRule`) to [all classes in your entire suite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633184/2032064):

   ```
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class})
    public class SuiteWithTimeout {
        @ClassRule
        public static Timeout classTimeout = new Timeout(1000);

        @Rule
        public Timeout timeout = new Timeout(100);
    }
   ```

EDIT:
timeout was deprecated recently to utilize this initialization

```
@Rule
public Timeout timeout = new Timeout(120000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You should provide the Timeunit now, as this will provide more granularity to your code.

Comment: Nice. I stopped using JUnit quite some time back. The last option looks good, although what I was looking for at the time was a way to timeout all tests run from Ant/Gradle globally so as to enforce, say, a 1 second timeout for every test in the project (essentially as a constraint for everyone working in this 400-person project to contend with).

Comment: If I use @Rule with espresso and Robolectric the tests fail with 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()'

Comment: To use this in Kotlin, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945087/kotlin-and-new-activitytestrule-the-rule-must-be-public

Answer (score 8):

If you use JUnit 4 and `@Test`, you can specifiy the `timeout` parameter that will fail a tests that's taking longer than specified. Downside for that is that you'd have to add it to every test method.

A probably better alternative is the use of a `@Rule` with [`org.junit.rules.Timeout`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/Timeout.html). With this, you can do it per class (or even in a shared super class).

Comment: The Timeout `@Rule` is nice. Pity you can't do this on a `@Suite`. Or can you?

Comment: Hmm.  Rather than adding @Rule to every class, I wonder if there's a relatively easy way to add it to all the classes at runtime?

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa - You can use a custom test case base class as you used to do with Junit 3. Not ideal but a decent workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I know from the tags that this question was aimed at JUnit 4, but in JUnit 5 (Jupiter), the [mechanism has changed](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Timeout.html).

From the [guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts):

> ```java
>    @Test
>    @Timeout(value = 500, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
>    void failsIfExecutionTimeExceeds500Milliseconds() {
>        // fails if execution time exceeds 500 milliseconds
>    }
> ```

(The `unit` defaults to seconds, so you could just use `@Timeout(1)`.)

It's easy to apply once across a class:

> To apply the same timeout to all test methods within a test class and all of its @Nested classes, you can declare the @Timeout annotation at the class level.

For your purposes, you might even experiment with top-level configuration on your build jobs:

> "junit.jupiter.execution.timeout.test.method.default"
> Default timeout for @Test methods