# Kotlin and new ActivityTestRule : The @Rule must be public

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, kotlin

I'm trying to make UI test for my android app in Kotlin. Since the new system using ActivityTestRule, I can't make it work: it compiles correctly, and at runtime, I get:

```
java.lang.Exception: The @Rule 'mActivityRule' must be public.
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.addError(RuleFieldValidator.java:90)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validatePublic(RuleFieldValidator.java:67)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validateField(RuleFieldValidator.java:55)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.rules.RuleFieldValidator.validate(RuleFieldValidator.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateFields(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:170)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:38)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.buildAndroidRunner(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:57)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:45)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.classes(TestRequestBuilder.java:691)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:654)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:329)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:226)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Here is how I declared mActivityRule:

```
RunWith(javaClass<AndroidJUnit4>())
LargeTest
public class RadisTest {

    Rule
    public val mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(javaClass<MainActivity>())

   ...
}
```

It is already public :/

Comment: Currently, Kotlin does not support making fields that are backing properties public, but we are working on it

Comment: Is there a bug tracking this?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3441

Answer (score 397, accepted):

JUnit allows providing rules through a test class field or a getter method.

What you annotated is in Kotlin a *property* though, which JUnit won't recognize.

Here are the possible ways to specify a JUnit rule in Kotlin:

### Through an annotated getter method

[From M13](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/), the annotation processor [supports annotation targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html).
When you write

```
@Rule
public val mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(javaClass<MainActivity>())
```

though, the annotation will use the `property` target by default (not visible to Java).

You can annotate the property getter however, which is also public and thus satisfies JUnit requirements for a rule getter:

```
@get:Rule
public val mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(javaClass<MainActivity>())
```

Alternatively, you can define the rule with a function instead of a property (achieving manually the same result as with `@get:Rule`).

### Through an annotated public field

Kotlin also allows [since the beta candidate](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-1-0-beta-candidate-is-out/) to deterministically compile properties to fields on the JVM, in which case the annotations and modifiers apply to the generated field. This is done using Kotlin's [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) property annotation as [answered by @jkschneider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815999/3055345).

---

Side note: be sure to prefix the `Rule` annotation with an `@` character as it is now [the only supported syntax for annotations](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/), and avoid `@publicField` as it [will soon be dropped](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/call-for-feedback-upcoming-changes-in-kotlin/).

Comment: Does it? I still get the error and it is public with M14 (0.14.449)

Comment: seems to need @publicField, but it is deprecated, so I tried lateinit as suggested by IDE, but then it barks at me saying lateinit can be applied only on mutable (the blog's article says otherwise…)

Comment: Updated my answer ;) As for `lateinit val`, it has been removed in M14 since it didn't fully enforce the immutability of the field, see the [M14 release blog post](blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-m14-is-out/).

Comment: What is @get: annotation? It also does not work in my situation.

Comment: After changing Rule to @get: Rule, it was fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 270):

With Kotlin 1.0.0+, this works:

```
@Rule @JvmField 
val mActivityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: And it solved the problem of the lint tool complaining that the public was qualifier on the rule was redundant.

Comment: Yes \@JvmField  is crucial or use rather \@get:Rule

Comment: Only works on final fields. Won't work for a rule like `var wireMockRule = WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort())`.

Answer (score 28):

Use this:

```
@get:Rule
var mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation?

Answer (score 24):

Instead of `@Rule` , you should use `@get:Rule`.

Answer (score 12):

With Kotlin 1.0.4:

```
val mActivityRule: ...
    @Rule get
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13929314)

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya - I did a check and this answer provides an answer to what has been asked. More information on how this is working can be found at the following link - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. If you want to access the activity under test (for example: assertTrue(activityRule.activity.isFinishing)), the property getter will be called, thus creating a new rule. In this case activityRule.activity will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @marci, take this example to clarify the concept:

```
@get:Rule val tempFolder = TemporaryFolder() //apply @Rule annotation to property getter
```