# Android test in kotlin of realm

Tags: android, testing, realm, kotlin

How can be done a simple test of a realm database in Android implementing the test in Kotlin?

I attempted to adapt a fragment from java realm [test on github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleRealmTest.java) to kotlin and got the next code:

```
import io.realm.Realm 
import io.realm.log.RealmLog 
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers 
import org.junit.Assert

import org.junit.Test import org.junit.Before import org.junit.Rule
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when` 
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito 
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule

class DBTest {

    @Rule
    var rule = PowerMockRule()
    lateinit internal var mockRealm: Realm

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(RealmLog::class.java)
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Realm::class.java)

        val mockRealm = PowerMockito.mock(Realm::class.java)

        `when`(Realm.getDefaultInstance()).thenReturn(mockRealm)

        this.mockRealm = mockRealm
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldBeAbleToGetDefaultInstance() {
        Assert.assertThat(Realm.getDefaultInstance(), CoreMatchers.`is`(mockRealm))
    }

}
```

But when I execute the test I get:

```
org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @Rule 'rule' must be public.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make the getter of the rule public like so:

```
@get: Rule
var rule = PowerMockRule()
```

Or you can mark it as a Java style field with the `@JvmField` annotation:

```
@JvmField @Rule
var rule = PowerMockRule()
```

You can find more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827600/4465208

Ps. You should also consider making it a `val` if you don't intend on changing its value anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, "@get Rule" fixed the problem. Now I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/Enhancer but this is another question.

Answer (score -1):

Realm java 4.1.0 has been released and most problem of Realm with Kotlin has resolved! . You can test [my sample project](https://github.com/c2c2/RealmKotlinShop) to see how you must config project or create classes. My sample is for testing module in Realm object Server with kotlin.