# Error in setting up realm with kotlin

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I am using some kotlin classes in an existing Android project(already having realm), the kotlin classes are not using any realm feature, now on runtime I am getting this error

```
:app:compileDebugKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Destination for generated sources was modified by kapt. Previous value = /home/debu/AndroidStudioProjects/WT_Application/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug

error: Annotation processor '__gen.AnnotationProcessorWrapper_debug_io_realm_processor_RealmProcessor' not found
1 error

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:app:copyDebugKotlinClasses SKIPPED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

my app's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    def globalConfiguration = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    compileSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidCompileSdkVersion")
    buildToolsVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidBuildToolsVersion")
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidApplicationId")
        minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")
        versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
        versionName globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner globalConfiguration.getAt("testInstrumentationRunner")
        /*jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }*/
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def presentationDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationDependencies
    def presentationTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationTestDependencies
    def developmentDependencies = rootProject.ext.developmentDependencies
    compile presentationDependencies.dagger
    compile presentationDependencies.butterKnife
    compile presentationDependencies.recyclerView
    compile presentationDependencies.cardview
    compile presentationDependencies.rxJava
    compile presentationDependencies.rxAndroid
    compile presentationDependencies.appcompat
    compile presentationDependencies.constraintLayout
    compile presentationDependencies.design
    compile presentationDependencies.retrofit
    compile presentationDependencies.gsonconverter
    compile presentationDependencies.rxjavaadapter
    compile presentationDependencies.glide
    compile presentationDependencies.flexbox
    compile presentationDependencies.maps
    compile presentationDependencies.mapUtils
    compile presentationDependencies.pagerIndicator
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.butterKnifeCompiler
    provided presentationDependencies.javaxAnnotation
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.junit
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.mockito
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.dexmaker
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.dexmakerMockito
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.espresso
    androidTestCompile presentationTestDependencies.testingSupportLib
    //Development

    compile developmentDependencies.leakCanary
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

project build.gradle

```
apply from: 'buildsystem/dependencies.gradle'
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        androidApplicationId = 'com.wandertrails'
        androidVersionCode = 1
        androidVersionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testApplicationId = 'com.wandertrails.test'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now can someone kindly figure out what is the reason of this error????

Comment: Please try to add the annotation processor dependencies to the `kapt` configuration as well: `kapt presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler`, `kapt presentationDependencies.butterKnifeCompiler`, and see if it works.

Comment: now I am getting the following error - 

Error:Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileDebugKotlin
\--- :app:kaptDebugKotlin
     \--- :app:compileDebugKotlin (*)
(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

Comment: If you are using Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha1, then the circular dependency is a known issue caused by Data Binding, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035504/how-to-use-data-binding-and-kotlin-in-android-studio-3-0-0; Probably the workaround described there (reverting to Kotlin 1.1.2-2 and disabling IC) will fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android test in kotlin of realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528039/android-test-in-kotlin-of-realm)

Answer (score 3):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

And

```
kapt presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler
kapt presentationDependencies.butterKnifeCompiler
```

Might fix it.

Comment: after adding the lines errors are gone -
annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler
    annotationProcessor presentationDependencies.butterKnifeCompiler
    kapt presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler
    kapt presentationDependencies.butterKnife
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.2"

now a new problem arrives, butterknife not working(BK ver - 8.6.0, Gradle ver - 3.4.1)

Comment: @Debu Would you please accept this answer?  This question has nothing to do with Butterknife.  You'll want to open a new question for that.