# RuntimeException: Delegate runnerfor AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded

Tags: java, android, junit, android-instrumentation

I am trying to do an instrumentation test using Android Studio for my  `MainActivity.java` class using Junit4. I don't know if my code is correct or not but this is my test class code:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest{

    private EditText edt;
    private TextView txt;

    @Rule
    ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        edt = activityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt);
        txt = activityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }

    @Test
    public void edt_text_change() {
        //i want this test to be passed
        assertEquals("147", "147");
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

But when i run that class, Android Studio shows me this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded.
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.throwInitializationError(AndroidJUnit4.java:92)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:82)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:51)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:153)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:73)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:793)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:547)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:390)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1890)
```

Answer (score 10):

Removing `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` annotations from the test classes fixed the issue, although I can't really say why or how it fixed it.

Edit: Allright I did some more testing. I migrated my app to Kotlin, and suddenly I noticed the tests began to work with the `@RunWith` annotation, too. Here's what I found out:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) // <-- @RunWith + @BeforeClass = Error
public class AndroidXJunitTestJava {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        // Setting up once before all tests
    }

    @Test
    public void testing() {
        // Testing....
    }
}
```

This java test fails with the `Delegate runner for AndroidJunit4 could not be loaded` error. But If I remove the `@RunWith` annotation, it works. Also, if I replace the `@BeforeClass` setup with just a `@Before`, like this:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) // <-- @RunWith + @Before = works?
public class AndroidXJunitTestJava {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Setting up before every test
    }

    @Test
    public void testing() {
        // Testing....
    }
}
```

The tests will run without errors. I needed to use the `@BeforeClass` annotation, so I just removed `@RunWith`.

But now that I am using Kotlin, the following (which should be equal to the first java example) works:

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.BeforeClass
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AndroidXJunitTest {

    companion object {
        @BeforeClass fun setup() {
            // Setting up
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testing() {
        // Testing...
    }

}
```

Also, as [Alessandro Biessek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934007/10518087) said in an answer and @Ioane Sharvadze in the comments, the same error can happen with the `@Rule` annotation. If I add a line

```
 @Rule val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

To the Kotlin example, the same delegate runner error happens. This must be replaced with

```
@get:Rule val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945087/kotlin-and-new-activitytestrule-the-rule-must-be-public#32827600). This is how i fixed my issue

Answer (score 4):

One more possible reason for this error is that you could accidentally miss that method with `@Before` annotation isn't **void** *(Unit)*. It's super easy when you use Kotlin:

```kotlin
@Before
fun setupSearch() = runBlocking {
    dao.saveSearchResults(listOf(testResult1, testRestult2), testSearchId))
}
```

If the last line in `runBlocking` block returns something, `setupSearch` won't be **void**.
To fix that specify generic parameter explicitly

```
@Before
fun setupSearch() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    dao.saveSearchResults(listOf(testResult1, testRestult2), testSearchId))
}
```

*I know that it doesn't directly answer Hadi's question, this answer is for people who googled `java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegate runner 'androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner' for AndroidJUnit4 could not be loaded.` and found this question, hope it will be useful for somebody.*

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, I've got the exact same error because a bad copy/paste: I had a `@Test` annotation on a method with some parameters.
The test crashes without any explicit information.

```
  @Test
  public void myCrashTest(String value) {
    Log.i("TEST", "TEST");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This should be the correct answer. At least it's a really common trap I assume

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, I forgot to add @Test annotation to my test function.