# “Wanted but not invoked; However there were other interactions with this mock” error

Tags: java, junit, mockito, assert

The unit test keeps giving me =

```
Wanted but not invoked: However, there were exactly 3 interactions with this mock.
```

All I am trying to do is, testing the timeout for a method execution - if the method takes more time, then terminate it and publish count(to understand the timed out response rate) as metric.

```java
@Test
public void testTimeoutFunction() throws Exception {
    Response response = getResponseForTest();

    when(processor
            .process(any(Request.class)))
            .thenAnswer((Answer<Response>) invocation -> {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                return response;
            });

    when(itemRequest.getRequestContext()).thenReturn(itemRequestContext);

    testClass = spy(new TestClass(processor, executorService));
    List<Item> output = testClass.getItemList(ID, itemRequest);

    verify(testClass, times(1)).responseTimedOutCount();
    assertTrue(output.isEmpty());
    verify(testClass, timeout(EXECUTION_TIMEOUT)).buildResponse(itemRequest);
    verify(testClass, times(1)).buildResponse(itemRequest);
}
```

This is method which I am testing for:

```java
public class TestClass {

    @VisibleForTesting
    void  responseTimedOutCount() {
    //log metrics
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Response> getResponseAsync(final ScheduledExecutorService delayer,
                                                                             final ItemRequest itemRequest) {
        return timeoutWithTimeoutFunction(delayer, EXECUTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(itemRequest), executorService),
                Response.emptyResponse(), () -> responseTimedOutCount());
    }


    private Response getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(final ItemRequest itemRequest) {
        //do something and return response
    }

    public List<Item> getItemList(final String id, final ItemRequest itemRequest) throws Exception {

        final ScheduledExecutorService delayer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Response response;
        if(validateItemId(id){
            try {
                response = getResponseAsync(delayer, itemRequest).get();
            } catch (final Throwable t) {
                response = Response.emptyResponse();
            } finally {
                delayer.shutdown();
            }
            return transform(response, id).getItems(); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception from Junit :

For this assert -

```
verify(testClass, times(1)).responseTimedOutCount();

Wanted but not invoked:
testClass.responseTimedOutCount(); 

However, there were exactly 3 interactions with this mock:
testClass.getItemList(ID, itemRequest);
testClass.validateItemId(ID);
testClass.getResponseWithTimeoutFunction(itemRequest);
```

Comment: The code you've posted never calls (never even mentions)  `getResponseTimedOutCount()`  (although it does call `responseTimedOutCount()`)

Comment: It's really quite hard to tell through the code you've posted what you are trying to achieve. You have skipped some code required to make this work so it's hard to tell if that's relevant or not. I suggest you produce a smaller, self-contained example that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to set up a per-test or per-class timeout when using <junit> in perBatch forkmode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743594/whats-the-best-way-to-set-up-a-per-test-or-per-class-timeout-when-using-junit)